# Can I sue my roommate in small claims court in Texas?

Tags: small-claims-court

There were three of us living in an apartment and one roommate had her name (Bianca) on the electricity and we would all pay our share when it was due. However, the other roommate (Cindy) who did not have her name on the electricity bill would always pay late resulting with delinquency notices for Bianca. After six months of delinquency notices Bianca asked Cindy to pay on time and this made Cindy upset. Cindy then stated she would put her name on the electricity bill. Two months passed and she did not put her name on the bill which resulted with vacancy fees on All three of our bills. This is student housing so there is a third-party company that fronts the bill for the city and then charges us extra because there was no name on the bill. When I brought the attention to Cindy she stated she forgot to put her name on the bill but would take care of our extra fees herself. I have her stating this on multiple texts and emails where she specifically states she will pay for all subsequent fees for not putting her name on the electricity bill. She never did and has since stopped communicating to either of us. I am wondering if her agreement to pay our extra fees as a result of not putting her name on the electricity bill even though she stated she would before the fees accrued and then not following through is something I can take to small claims court. The total is $150 for just me.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I sue my roommate in small claims court in Texas?

Yes. Cindy's agreement to take care of the extra fees was a form of settlement in exchange for your, and Bianca's, waiver of other actions (such as commencing court proceedings against Cindy). Cindy's pattern of evasion evidences her breach of the terms of that settlement.

Having emails and texts was a good idea because these will make much easier to prove your claims as opposed to unverifiable, bare statements of the sort "*I said, she said*".

Main dispute aside, bringing this matter to Small Claims court will give you some exposure to legal proceedings (which most likely will involve mediation) as well as to presenting your merits in front of a judge. Although this will be short of full-fledged litigation, that exposure will help you not to be intimidated in a courtroom or court proceedings in general if/when other more serious matters (unrelated to this dispute and involving other parties) arise in the future.

Comment: Much appreciation for you help! I will move forward on this!

Comment: Nothing in this answer is incorrect. But most people who not choose to incur the time and effort involved in a small claims lawsuit for a $150 dollar dispute. While you would get your service of process fees and filing fees awarded to you if you prevailed, you would not receive compensation for the time you spend on the lawsuit, which would probably be at least a dozen hours including time spent collecting a judgment awarded if it is not paid voluntarily,. The Court could force her to pay the amount owed, but couldn't compel her to put her name on the bill.

Comment: @ohwilleke I agree that the court would not rule to compensate the OP for time spent on the proceedings. But, even if seen as a *toy* court, this is a good opportunity for the OP to get some valuable exposure to court proceedings. I (and surely you too) have seen *pro se* litigants trembling in a courtroom as they speak before the judge. Much of that nervousness has to do with the intimidation by, and lack of experience in, a court environment. Also it can teach the party in breach a lesson and that the OP is willing to escalate the matter if need be.